# Why I cannot add Using System.Xml.Linq in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

I read on http://thibautvs.com/blog/?p=851 that System.Xml.XmlDocument was removed and is now succeeded by System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.

But I cannot add this in silverlight:

```
System.Xml.Linq
```

though I can add

```
System.Xml
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to add a reference to the assembly `System.Xml.Linq` (which is in System.Xml.Linq.dll) to your project first. `System.Xml` is in System.Xml.dll - which is a different assembly.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)

In Silverlight projects the `System.Xml.Linq` assembly is located in Assemblies >  Extensions instead of Assemblies > Framework.